# Clustering markers with exceptions (Google maps android API)

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Iam looking for a way to cluster all my markers on google maps except of a few markers. These few markers may vary from time to time. Means for example: All markers contain an information like a number for instance. If the user watches the map of Europe all markers shall be clustered except of those 3 markers with the highest number. If the user moves to North America on the map or zooms out to see the whole world, all markers shall again/still be clustered except of the 3 markers containing the highest number. These 3 markers could now of course be different markers.

Any idea where and how to start is warmly appreciated. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible.

For a marker to be clusterizable you have to explicitly add it to a `ClusterManager` doing `mClusterManager.addItem(myClusterizableItem);` (See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#simple)).

So, you only need to add all the markers to the `ClusterManager` and create some markers (the ones you don't want to cluster) the usual way using the `mMap.addMarker` method.

Another way could be to write a custom `ClusterRenderer` that clusters your markers based on some conditions and exclude the markers you don't want to cluster.

Comment: thx! but does this also work when the exceptions (means non clustered markers) are changing, due to the behaviour of users? I mean, in case a user "likes" a marker, the marker shall not be clustered anymore for all users using the App. I dont see a way here so far :(.

Comment: Yes, when a user "likes" a Marker you have to tell your server and the next requests will receive some markers as clusterizable and some others as non clusterizable and your client will have to cluster the markers based on that